# Short phrase for "things I did (wrote, drew, created, etc) when I was younger"?

Tags: single-word-requests, metaphors, phrase-requests

What's a one or two word phrase that conveys the meaning "These are some things that I did when I was younger."?  The context is a blog that features Writings, Photography, and Artwork. The short phrase will be used as a possible category of the blog's posts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Juvenilia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juvenilia) is the word I would use here.

Comment: I like it..  A fancy word for a wordsmith's site.

Comment: I had never heard this word but I certainly like it. I will definitely be trying to shoe-horn it into conversation for the next few days!

Comment: new to me, but instantly comprehensible without even bothing to follow the link. Great potential for distinguishing "Immature early work" (which may be only of academic interest) and "Early work" (far more likely to include some truly artistic offerings).

Comment: Depending on the context such a word is presenting in, you may find that your visitors have no idea what the link leads to.

Answer (score 5):

**Childish scribblings** may be what you're looking for though it is a touch negative.

**Youthful endeavours** could serve too

and failing that

**early works** though depending on the quality of the earlier work it might make you sound like you take yourself a touch too seriously.

Comment: I like "Youthful Endeavors".  It's a good middle ground between Childish scribblings and early works.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Crayonings](http://www.wordnik.com/words/crayoning).

Comment: That suggests stuff done when you were 10.

Comment: @apoorv: That's how I read the question. I pictured users posting stuff they did as kids. I see now that's a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

I note that others have taken "younger" to mean "teenage" or "childish", but I can't see anything in your question that implies either. So...

**Older creations**

**Previous works**

**From the vault**

**Early works**

**Lost treasures**

Or a mixture of some of these words.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have an answer but I immediately thought of *reminiscences*

Comment: *Reminiscences* are your memories of doing things, not the things themselves.